# Simulating purchase in Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a strange problem with in-app purchase in Windows Store App.
When I upload app to the Store I see a pop-up like this:
[image]

But when I run in on my local machine, from release mode and using [CurrentApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp)
everything seems to be OK, I see checking price in Store:
[image]
Also the funny thing is that there is no difference when I am using [CurrentApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp) or [CurrentAppSimulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator).
Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Code for checking is commonly known:

```
public async Task<bool> IsPurchased(string featureName)
    {
        var applicationInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

        if (applicationInformation.ProductLicenses[featureName].IsActive)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(featureName);

            return applicationInformation.ProductLicenses[featureName].IsActive;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean 'When I upload to the store'? Do you mean that you've uploaded this app package, had it pass certification, downloaded it from the store, and this happens? Or do you mean when you create an app package for upload, sideload it, and then run it?

Comment: My app has passed the certification, I downloaded them from store and install, I have tried on two computers and the problem exists in both

Comment: Do you possibly have more than one implementation somewhere? It seems that you are calling `CurrentAppSimulator` instead of `CurrentApp`. Maybe try `ctrl+f` and looking for `CurrentAppSimulator` to see if you are using it anywhere accidentally?

Comment: No it was not this, I checked it before, but why it is displaying in Store not on my local machine?

Comment: One thing you may want to try is to create an app package for upload, then sideload it. Make sure to include symbols. You can still debug it from Visual Studio by going to `Debug -> Debug Installed App Package`. Set breakpoints around it and make sure the right code is being called, and that it's using `CurrentApp`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete all content from bin folder, clean solution and rebuild it.
Aftere these operation everything works OK.